Spain Schengen Visa Refusal
I applied for a Spanish tourist visa with my girlfriend last month and got a rejection letter two days ago. The only information provided was the ticking of box number 10 "The information submitted regarding the justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable". No other box was ticked.
The reason for rejection took us by surprise because we thought our itinerary was the strongest aspect of the application. We were going to attend a Padel holiday training camp that was happening at the same time as Premier Padel Malaga, so we were also going to watch the tournament finals. Our hotels and flights were pre-paid; we provided tickets for the finals, an invitation from the camp organizer (1, 2), and some pre-paid sightseeing tours. Do you have ideas on what would have been on the officer's mind when deciding to reject the application based on this reason? And thus, do you have any idea on how we can provide more proof regarding the purpose of travel? Our purpose of travel is legitimate, and I'm sure there's something we failed to deliver to the officer, but I'm not sure what it is at this point, so I'm seeking your help. I know there's another post regarding this reason but it states that it's often accompanied by "there are reasonable doubts as to your intention to leave the territory of the Member States before the expiry of the visa". In my case, it's only reason 10. How often this happens?
Here's more background in this post.
Although it will be impossible for us to make it to this camp, there is another similar camp happening in Madrid in September, and we plan to appeal or reapply hoping to be able to attend that event. Is it possible/advisable to appeal this rejected visa application for the records and also submit a new application for the new dates, or can an appeal be submitted for alternative dates? More importantly, how to know if something about our situation is wrong in their eyes, and thus we need to wait until changing it before reapplying, or if there's something that we failed to prove, and we just need stronger proof before reapplying.

I’m not sure why the decision came as a surprise. Your earlier question describes a digital nomad lifestyle with few tangible ties to your latest country of residence.

The reason is what came most as a surprise and, to a lesser extent, the decision. I consulted with a lawyer who told me that having a one-year lease agreement, especially since I prepaid six months of rent, can constitute strong ties. Also having the business in Indonesia.
They didn't tick "13 there are reasonable doubts as to your intention to leave the territory of the Member States before the expiry of the visa." From what I understand, that's the reason they tick when they think you don't have enough ties and thus are at risk of overstaying. That's where the confusion is coming from.

’Can constitute strong ties’ doesn’t = definitely will. Why do you particularly want to do the padel camp, and why in Spain specifically? Is padel a big thing in Indonesia? Do you play frequently/belong to a club there?

How do I know this relates to ties, not another reason? What I'm trying to figure out is whether something about our current situation is fundamentally wrong in their eyes and thus we need to wait until our situation changes before reapplying, or if there's something that we failed to prove, and we just need stronger proof before reapplying. For example, if the officer had an issue with our international income, there's nothing to change about that for now and maybe a digital nomad visa would be more suitable. Alternatively, if it's ties, maybe we should wait until we have more ties.

To answer your questions, I wanted to do the Padel camp because I've been obsessed with Padel for the past 6 months, and I want to improve my skills and watch the top players of the world train and play live. Spain is where the sport is most popular and where these camps usually happen, also it's where most padel coaches in the world come from (my coaches in Bali are Spanish and recommended going for such an experience). And yes, Padel is growing rapidly in Bali. I play almost every day in local clubs, have memberships, and watch the sport regularly on TV.

It's definitely not a made-up story, and going on a Padel holiday camp is one of the things I want most in life right now, lol.
I'm not sure if the VO is simply not believing that my real purpose is going to this camp or has another reason.

br88 - The onus here is on you to provide enough evidence to suggest you will not overstay. If the VO believes you do not have sufficient evidence then why would they accept your application?

This question is re-opened as I could not see how the others voted, but I want to give it a second chance after the edits. The lack of the more usual rejection reason does make it different.

Of course, the onus is on me. That's why I attached 500 pages to my application, giving strong proof of all the statements that I mentioned in my cover letter. It's just unclear if remote workers like me with international businesses and frequent travelers are eligible to short-stay visas and what kind of proof is needed.

@willeke, thanks for re-opening the question. I hope I can get an answer for how to proceed when you only get one reason for refusal: "The information submitted regarding the justification for the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not reliable," without the other options being ticked. Also hope to understand if remote workers and digital entrepreneurs like us can in fact, apply for stay visas or if our best bet is to apply for digital nomad visas.
